# Flask App Not Posting to Database

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, peewee

I can't seem to get this form to post data to my database. I'm working in the Flask framework for Python with the Peewee ORM. When I submit the form, I see a POST event execute (see below), but nothing is written to the database.

`[21/Nov/2015 04:21:47] "POST /create-event HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

I know the database connection itself is good because another write function is working. Below is the code along with an indication of which file it is in.

**app.py**

```
@app.route('/create-event', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@login_required
def create_event():
    form = forms.EventForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        models.Event.create(user=g.user.id,
                            name=form.name.data.strip(),
                            description=form.description.data.strip(),
                            date=form.date.data.strip()
                            )
        flash("Event created!", "success")
        return redirect(url_for('timeline'))
    return render_template('userpages/event_create.html', form=form)
```

**forms.py**

```
class EventForm(Form):
    name = StringField("Event Name", validators=[DataRequired()])
    description = TextAreaField("Description", validators=[DataRequired()])
    date = DateField("Date", validators=[DataRequired()])
```

**models.py**

```
class Event(Model):
    timestamp = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    user = ForeignKeyField(
        rel_model=User,
        related_name='events'
    )
    name = CharField()
    description = TextField()
    date = DateField()

    class Meta:
        database = DATABASE
        order_by = ('-timestamp',)
```

**event_create.html**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% from 'macros.html' import render_field %}

{% block content %}

<h1>Create New Event</h1>

<form method="POST" action="" class="form">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {% for field in form %}
        {{ render_field(field) }}
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Create</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: im not familliar enough with peewee but oftwn you need a `engine.commit()` somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Bad form to answer my own question, perhaps, but it looks like the main problem was that I had edited my model after the `event` table had already been created and the changes didn't apply properly. Deleting and recreating the table was what was needed.

The other problem is that you can't call `.strip()` on this date field.